# ProductName-Swift.h not updating on changing respective one of objective C file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I had,

```
public class Contact: NSObject {        
    var sName : String?
    var sUserEmail : String?
    var sUserCellNo : String?
}
```

and respective code in ProductName-Swift.h,

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_NAME_")
@interface Contact : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * sName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * sUserEmail;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * sUserCellNo;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

so i can access all these properties in my other objective C well.

Now i had to add new property in my Contact class so it becomes,

```
public class Contact: NSObject {
    var iUserAddressID : Int? //newly added
    var sName : String?
    var sUserEmail : String?
    var sUserCellNo : String?
}
```

but after cleaning-building I get ProductName-Swift.h same as previous,

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_NAME_")
    @interface Contact : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * sName;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * sUserEmail;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * sUserCellNo;
    - (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

So, I can not user newly added iUserAddressID. how to overcome this issue?

FYI : using xcode6 beta4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that it's balking at translating `Int?` to ObjC. That doesn't have an obvious form in ObjC. It could be an `NSNumber` or it could be an `NSInteger*`. Neither is a particularly common approach for this kind of problem in ObjC (it's more common to use a "magic value" like `NSNotFound` or -1). You can probably address this by making it an `NSNumber?` rather than an `Int?`. Swift callers should automatically bridge for you.

If you're not getting any warnings, I would open a radar about that. You should probably get some indication if an `NSObject` subclass cannot be converted all the way to ObjC.

This feels like you're trying to create foreign keys in an object data structure. If so, the better solution would be to create a `UserAddress` class and make your variable point to that rather than to an Int (then optionals will work fine).

Comment: It still does this as of Xcode 8, with no warning either - in my case with a `Bool?`